# CreateViewRequest for multiple signees to build a smart signing ceremony

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope with more than 2 signees and more than 1 document.

The desired behavior for the signing ceremony is that once a signee completed its signature, it should redirect to the next signee document session, and so on, until the last signee completes the envelope, and it redirects to my website.

The signees are present, so no remote signing is needed.

I know one way is by generating them from my website dynamically [using this approach](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls).

Is there an easier way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs must be generated dynamically because they expire after 2 minutes for security reasons.
Just remember that each signer has to have a `clientUserId` that must match the request to generate a URL for that signer and that you need to have some logic with your `returnUri` that goes back to your app for the next signer.

Other than that - nothing else is any different for your scenario.